# Is there a nice way to select / navigate between 2 ends of an input tag with nested input tags

Tags: vim, neovim

The best example I have is found in some of the react development I do, where I may have a component like

```
<MyComponent
   foo={bar}
   leftFooSection={<FooBar/>}
   ...
   label={'yes'} />
```

and I want to select everything form the starting `<` to the final `/>` inclusively.

obviously things like vat or vit work well when you have a proper closing tag, but is there anything that works for when you don't?

Currently using `vi<` or `vi>` will only select up to the inner `/>`. I'm hoping to select all the way down to the final `/>` of the actual component

Comment: `i>` selects the whole component, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visual-select everything inside the angle brackets, you can use the `i>` and `a>` (`i<` and `a<` will work as well) motions. Typing `vi>` will select everything inside the tag.

This will also work for nested structures as explained in `:help i>`.

If your cursor is already *inside* the inner angle brackets, supply a count such as `v2i>` to select the outer brackets. Or just leave them first with e.g. `^`, `$`, `j` or whatever applies to get out.

To jump to the **o**ther end of a visual selection, `o` can be used.

Comment: the problem I'm running into is when there's a nested <> it will only include up to the inner >.

I wasn't sure if I could number modifier or something ta handle these special cases

Comment: @iamaword this implies the cursor is inside the inner brackets. I edited to account for this case as well.